# Get-ChildItem -Recurse do not search recursively when regex pattern provided

Tags: powershell

The last dev had a system that copies every file in shadow has `._FILENAME` and it takes a lot of space (double of the original file) in the project.

Example :

```
._index.php 500kb
._menu.php 600kb
index.php 250kb
menu.php 300kb
```

I'm trying to make a little script that will delete all `._FILENAME`, but it looks like it only scans the active folder and does not goes recursively in all subfolders?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -File -Include * -Recurse  | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\._.*$' } | foreach { echo "Deleting: $_"}
```

Comment: Does `Get-ChildItem -Path $currentfolder -File -Include * -Recurse` work properly if used without `Where-Object`?

Comment: Yes it return everything

Comment: And if you write it like this: `$AllResults = Get-ChildItem -Path $currentfolder -File -Include * -Recurse; $FilteredResults = $AllResults | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\._.*$' }`? Would `$AllResults`, `$FilteredResults` contains subfolders results?

Comment: Are the files hidden?  What if you add `-Hidden` as an argument to `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: I tried to reproduce and it works as expected. I assume `$currentfolder` does not contain the expected path!?

Comment: $currentfolder contain the expected path...

Comment: I found I need -Force to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to achieve my needs by adding -Force after -Recurse. I still don't know why, and that's kind of weird behavior for me.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Include * -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\._.*$' } | foreach { echo "Deleting: $_"  ; $_.Delete() } | Out-File deleted.txt
```

I added Out-File deleted.txt so it's output everything into a text file so I can refer to it after the operation.